Bizarre and insulting edit on my Answer on Christian Arabs not using Allah name for God before Islam, he deleted my answer after I rejected his edit
I found a shocking and insulting edit by a moderator on my answer which ridicules an Arab Christian scholar (Christian Prince) and also the whole answer by editing to look like I am presenting an anti-Islamic caricature and propaganda of fringe beliefs and not a reasonable scholarly position. Their edit is showing in the red, as I have rolled back to a previous edit. Had I not found the rollback option, the answer couldn't have been restored. This bizarre and biased edit is in favour of anti-Christian hateful view, and no person should be allowed to make such judgmental biased edits which totally mocks and twists the answer. If you disagree with answers, then you may choose to down vote, which you seem to have done, but don't make bogus hateful edits.
And now a moderator has deleted the answer.
On a side note, the answer to the question depends on the linguistic comparison for the Arabic word for God and the name Allah, since, we don't seem to have Arabic Bibles from before the time of Islam.

The answer was deleted because it violates the Code of Conduct. It misrepresents a fringe theory that’s currently widely discredited as factual. Furthermore, it also links to off-site content that contains a list of videos that include Dangerous speech, Dehumanization, Hateful imagery, and Mocking content, against Muslims.
Such content is not acceptable and does not contribute to an academic discussion of the topic but a list of videos that promote an Islamaphobic ideology. That is not ok and we do not allow the promotion of extremist content.
A moderator edited your answer after we discussed the case with them. When you decided to roll back the edit, it was then deleted. While this is a site about the Christian faith, it is also a secular site, and those who set forth to answer questions must do so in an academic and neutral tone without abuse or bias as set by site guidelines and the Code of Conduct.

I can remove name of that Arab Christian scholar whom you hate, but the mod attacked my whole theory or answer as fringe that Allah does not mean God in Arabic, secondly, Allah is the name of the Lunar deity. These two points are the basis of my answer for which I used scholarly sources https://www.britannica.com/topic/Sin-Mesopotamian-god . If you accept the answer without that youtuber Arab Christian's reference, I will happily edit it. You could just asked me that in comments instead of such offensive edits.

I have edited it, if you wish you can undelete the answer. It cannot be made more palatable than this.

I am still struggling to understand why this entire subject is being brought up on a site called 'Christianity' where we academically examine (in a comparative way) what self-identifying 'Christians' have to say to one another. Staff Mod's answer up-voted +1.

Socialist Blasphemy Law in action : I was banned for a week

Some of your recent interactions with other community members have
violated our Code of Conduct.
In particular, we would like to call out the following interactions as
being problematic and having contributed to sending this message:

The name of Allah has been mistakenly believed to be derived from the contraction of al-ilah (the-God) among Muslims; though linguistic
and the authentic Islamic sources have cleared this popular
misconception.


there wouldn't be any proper name for the Islamic god (not that there has to be a proper name for this god).

Your recent interactions are clear violations of our Code of Conduct
specifically of our Abusive behavior policy which states we do not
allow:

Bullying and Harassment - severe, repeated, or persistent unsolicited conduct, misuse of power or tools, or attacks that target
specific users or groups of people in a manner that causes harm.
Content that contributes to a hostile or threatening environment,
denies a person's expressed gender identity, or invalidates a person's
individual experiences in a manner that causes harm.

Also included in that post are violations of the Misleading
information policy in particular this paragraph:

Morphological segmenting of al-Lah can help in understanding the etymology, when al is taken to be a cognate of the Syrio-Aramaic or
Semitic el for deity; also compare the three goddesses al-lat, al-uzza
and Manat. Also compare like the Christian God's name Yaweh, a similar
apparent Syrian name for the Islamic god in the Quran, that is Ya-Sin
(the title of chapter 36 in Quran), meaning God-Sin, a Mesopotamian
lunar deity.

As stated previously this portion of your answer misrepresents a
fringe theory that’s currently widely discredited as factual and as
per the Code of Conduct we do not allow content that:

Promotes the specific views of a party, government, or ideology by using false claims regarding others

You need to cease this behavior if you wish to continue participating
in our websites; future violations will result in further action, up
to your profile being suspended for several months or years.
Your account has been temporarily suspended for 7 days. While you’re
suspended, your reputation will show as 1 but will be restored once
the suspension ends.

This list of accusations are defamatory and frankly extremely pathological. I couldn't imagine that the view that the allah of Islam is a name of a crescent God would be so threatening to the moderators of the Christianity:SE. The claim that it is a fringe theory is totally false. The fact that Muslims scholars cannot admit various archaeological and theological, linguistic origin of Islam is to protect their lives as they don't wanna get beheaded. As a result, the Islamic scholarship is exclusively limited within Europe. The level of such censorship is only seen on certain highly controversial innovative mandatory medical procedure which was deemed beyond any question.
Secondly, I edited out the controversial reference to Christian Prince and focused on the name Sin of Allah, which is another Syrian name of the Mesopotamian crescent moon God, and you conveniently declared that as a misrepresentation of that "fringe theory". I sought your permission to undelete the question, and the mod who first deleted the answer undeleted it, but after 3 days, another mod deleted it and banned me.
I am not going to continue defending the position of Al-Lah being a moon God, even though it is crucial and relevant to the question.
Likewise, I have edited that remaining references, now kindly undelete it as you have no reason left to find it offensive. Your charges against me were abusive and biased, yet I have removed those references. Let me see if your team is really as secular as you claim. I have made no insult and prejudice to Islam in my answer, rather I quoted authentic Islamic as well as Arabic academic sources.
An answer which is completely respectful, without intending to harm anyone's feeling, and valuable with scholarly citation along with your highest source of reliability "Wikipedia".
